# Bigquery-Update command

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to update values of column page in my table page_perf.but i keep getting error message:**Encountered " "UPDATE" "update "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting:**

Code:

```
update 'possible-stock-172109:180417Page_dataset.page'
    set unique_id = LEFT(SUBSTR(page,5,22),22)
    where Product = "HT_AMP";
```

Comment: did you try removing inverted commas from the table name ?

Comment: yes.The new error :Error: Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting: "SET" ...

Comment: Uncheck the box for "Use legacy SQL" under the options menu. The error message is most likely telling you to use standard SQL as well.

Comment: did that also.new error: Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'possible-stock-172109:180417Page_dataset.page' at [1:8]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

- The query needs to use standard SQL. You cannot use an UPDATE statement with BigQuery legacy SQL.
- The query needs to use the expected table format for standard SQL, not legacy SQL.
- The query needs to use standard SQL functions. `LEFT` is not a supported function, for example.

It looks like the intent is to run a query like this:

```
#standardSQL
update `possible-stock-172109.180417Page_dataset.page`
set unique_id = SUBSTR(page,5,22)
where Product = "HT_AMP";
```